# Why people are saying TCP potocol is end to end potocol?

Tags: networking

There are two potocols in transport layer.Someone can explain me about what are the tasks of those potocols..

Comment: Maybe research on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ This is pretty much off-topic for [SO] and is way to broad anyway.

Comment: The word you are looking for is *protocol.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*There are two potocols in tranceport layer.*"

There are actually [many transport-layer protocols](https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml). I think you mean the two most common Transport protocols: [TCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) and [UDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768).

TCP is an end-to-end protocol because it is connection-oriented. One TCP establishes a connection to another TCP. TCP guarantees segment delivery.

UDP is a connectionless, best-effort, fire-and-forget protocol that sends a datagram and doesn't care whether or not it is received.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the transport layer protocols abstract the lower levels (network layer, link layer, physical layer) and they work only considering the existence of the two final communicating entities, abstracting everything that is in the way.